# Random memory leak while reading xlsx files using C#

Tags: c#, xlsx

I am new to C# and wpf but am trying to read a lot of data (abt. 40000 x 34 cells) from +100 xlsx files and concatenate them into a text file.

I have made a small C# (wpf) app to do that. I see somewhat random memory leak, where sometimes as I run it, everything goes well and the memory it requires (according to windows task manager) stays under 1 GB, while other times it eats, almost all of my 8 GB.

One situation I have found happens when using `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathtotextfilewithxlsxfilenames)`
whereas using the discreet example (specifying the filenames in the code) does not in the same way seem to cause the problem. (I have copied and pasted the same names from the text file with xlsx-filenames to the code (replaced tabs with `", "`) so it should be equal.. as far as I understand).

The app is roughly like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WpfApps
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
  string s_path_to_list_of_xlsx_files;
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    string path = @"F:\...\xls_files\";
    string[] fnlist = { "datafile1.xlsx", "datafile2.xlsx", ... "datafileN.xlsx" };

    //string[] fnlist = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"f:\...\xlsfiles.txt"); // It seems as if using this line, compared to the discreet line above causes memory leak.
    DataTable measurementdata = new DataTable();
    measurementdata.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(double));
    measurementdata.Columns.Add("C2", typeof(double));
    ...
    measurementdata.Columns.Add("C34", typeof(double));

    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path + "allresult.txt"))
    {
      bool firstCol = true;
      foreach (DataColumn col in measurementdata.Columns)
      {
        if (!firstCol) sw.Write(", ");
        sw.Write(col.ColumnName);
        firstCol = false;
      }
      sw.WriteLine();
    }
    foreach (var fn in fnlist)
    {
        DataTable filedt = GetDataTableFromExcel(path + fn, false);
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path + "allresult.txt"))
        {
          foreach (DataRow row in filedt.Rows)
          {
              bool firstCol = true;
              foreach (DataColumn col in filedt.Columns)
              {
                if (!firstCol) sw.Write(", ");
                sw.Write(row[col].ToString());
                firstCol = false;
              }
              sw.WriteLine();
          }
        }
    }
  }

  public static DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(string path, bool hasHeader = true)
  {
    using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
          pck.Load(stream);
        }
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Logged Data"];
        int startrow = 72;
        int endrow = 43271;
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        foreach (var firstrowcell in ws.Cells[startrow - 1, 8, startrow - 1, 41])
        {
              tbl.Columns.Add(firstrowcell.Text);
        }
        for (int rowNum = startrow; rowNum <= endrow; rowNum++)
        {
          var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 8, rowNum, 41];
          DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
          foreach (var cell in wsRow)
          {
              var cellvalue = cell.Value;
              if (cellvalue == null) cellvalue = "0";
              row[cell.Start.Column - 8] = cellvalue;
          }
        }
        return tbl;
    }
  }
```

Can anyone see an obvious problem?

Comment: Nested using statements can be a source of leaks http://superdevelopment.com/2014/03/13/common-pitfalls-with-idisposable-and-the-using-statement/

Comment: @ojf not really - only if the implementation of `Dispose()` is buggy, or if the order of disposal is reversed (another bug).  Even the article you linked to admits this

Comment: Your code loads *all* Excel files in memory, before writing it out again. If you load a lot of data, you'll consume a lot of memory.  Read and output the files one at a time, or even better, rewrite your code to write a text line immediately after reading an Excel row.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I thought that wasn't the case using `foreach (var fn in fnlist)`. That it takes each file by itself in order.... How else to do that if not using a for loop???

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this. The code needs some indentation fixes. You are still loading a lot of data in memory though, which won't be cleared until the garbage collector runs. You can save memory in *many* ways. For example, there's no need to use a DataTable if all you want to do is export the values to a CSV file. You could store the temporary row values into a list and call `String.Join` inside the Excel reading function to generate the final string. You could reuse the same List by clearing it in every row iteration, so no extra memory is used for each line

Comment: `DataTable` implements `IDisposable` interface, so you should `Dispose` `DataTable`s too. Also, have you tried running the program in `Release` mode and without debugger attached?